# Wordpress MultiSite with ISAPI filters

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, isapi, isapi-rewrite

I just have installed Wordpress 3.5 to manage more than one domain with one installation (Multi-Site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

At the end of the installation, Wordpress shown me the follow code for `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) E:\example.com\www/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ E:\example.com\www/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm not using Apache as Web Server, I am on IIS with ISAPI Filters.

How can I convert the above code for ISAPI?

(I will put these instructions on ISAPI file named **httpd.ini**)

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should post such question related to wordpress at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, is it's a Helicon's ISAPI_Rewrite2, try searching their forum.
For example, links like [this](http://www.helicontech.com/forum/16603-wordpress_301_permalinks_with_isapi_2.html) can help you a lot. Their knowledge base is huge